# Failed DB update requests with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, sql-update

After spending numerous hours on this and scouring the answers online, I'm royally stuck on a seemingly simple DB update with Laravel. Here is a (simplified) version of the flawed function in one of my controllers:

```
public function changeDetails(Request $request)
    {

      ...

      // It works to change member_id into another...
      if (Request::input('recipient_id') != "null") {
        DB::table('recipients')
          ->where('recipients.id','=',Request::input('recipient_id'))
          ->update([
            'recipients.member_id' => Request::input('member_id')
          ]);
      // ...but it won't let me change it to NULL.
      } else {
        DB::table('recipients')
          ->where('recipients.id','=',Request::input('recipient_id'))
          ->update([
            'recipients.member_id' => null
          ]);
      };
```

I initially thought that the issue had to do with the database or table, especially since the 'member_id' is a foreign key. However, I did two tests that prove otherwise. First, I made sure that the column is 'unsigned' and 'nullable'. Second, I manually inserted an integer into the "where" clause instead of the "Request::input('recipient_id')"... and it worked fine. I also confirmed that the value of "Request::input('recipient_id')" is indeed an integer, which should work within the appropriate column (that is 'bigint' type).

Any useful suggestions/observations? They would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not check using`.......update(['member_id' => null])`

Comment: What's the actual error message you are getting? Try enabling the query log to see what is actually being queried on the database, put this at the beginning of your function: ```DB::enableQueryLog();``` and this after the query: ```dd(DB::getQueryLog())```.

Comment: I think @yuweiwei is on the right track... it's confusing (and gives me a slight uneasy feeling) to use a string of "null" as a response from your form and also set a null value in the column. In your select field in your form, if you are trying to "unset" a foreign key, you should choose something other than the string of "null". perhaps an empty string or  exclude the field from the form and use `if(Request::has('recipient_id'))`

Comment: Yeah, @TimJoyce, I had worried about the string `"null"` initially, but I tested the `if/else` and it passed. I didn't show it, but that value was from a `<select>` element, so it seems that it has to be a string. In hindsight, I should have named it anything but `"null"` haha

Comment: @Andrew, it hadn't shown me any error, which had made it even more frustrating. I'll have to try out things like `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` sometime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code runs into else statement only when Request::input('recipient_id') is "null",
but your else statement also uses 'recipient_id' which is "null".

So your SQL statement will find a recipients where recipients.id = "null".

Obviously you don't have any "recipient_id" is "null", right?

```
...
else {
    DB::table('recipients')
      ->where('recipients.id','=',Request::input('recipient_id')) // here the recipient_id is "null"
      ->update([
        'recipients.member_id' => null
      ]);
 };
...
```

Comment: Yeah, that's where the problem had been. Swapping the `->where('recipients.id)` with `->where('recipients.member_id)` solved it. Thanks for the help